# Null pointers to classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, null

I was trying to validate pointers in an array so I didn't cause any memory errors,

and this method:

```
for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++) {
     if (array[i]!=NULL)
          array[i]->stuff();
     }
}
```

has worked in the past.

Now, I have to do the same thing, except do it all in order based on an object variable.

My new method is:

```
Direct2Entity* nextset[MAX_ENTS]; // ents[MAX_ENTS] is also a Direct2Entity* array
for(int i=0;i<MAX_ENTS;i++) {
    nextset[i]=NULL; // note that ents[] is also flushed before this
}
int nextsetid=0;
int maxn;
bool stillnull;
while(true) { // infinite sorting loop
    maxn=-1;
    stillnull=true;
    for(int i=0;i<next_put;i++) {
        if (ents[i]!=NULL) {
            stillnull=false;
            if (ents[i]->depth<0) { // make sure no infinite loops occur with negative depth
                ents[i]->depth=0;
            }
            if (ents[i]->depth>maxn) {
                nextset[nextsetid++]=ents[i];
                ents[i]=NULL; // make NULL to further loop
            }
        }
    }
    if (stillnull) break;
}
for(int i=0;i<next_put;i++) {
    if (nextset[i]!=NULL) {
        ents[i]=nextset[i]; // copy nextset[] to ents[]
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<next_put;i++) {
    if (ents[i]!=NULL) {
        if (ents[i]->getroom()==current_room) {
            ents[i]->draw(this); // ents[i] is still NULL... ?
        }
    }
}
```

In the last for loop, ents[i] was explicitly checked to make sure it would not be dereferencing NULL pointers. Yet C++ goes past it and calls the function. There are all sorts of run time error in all sort of random places, but I am almost sure it is undefined behavior coming from here.

Comment: Step through your program with a debugger. It will tell you where exactly errors occur. You will be able to examine variables at any point and compare the values to your expectations.

Comment: After going through about 1,000 presses of f11, and 30 or so files of assembly language, I fixed the broken re-ordering algorithm. Do you have any tips to keep the step-into view on YOUR files only..?

Comment: @metredigm:  look up *breakpoints* in your debugger.  This allows execution to run until a breakpoint is encountered.  Some debuggers allow code to stop after *N* encounters of the breakpoint (look up trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the logic determining the value of next_put.  Is it possible that it simply exceeds the length of ents[]?  If so, even if you have properly initialized ents[], when your loop walks off the end of the array, that memory is not initialized (at least as you expect it to be) and your if (ents[i]!=NULL) will be passed (and then your program should crash).